# odd text behavior in chrome/IE 11/ firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I am encountering a peculiar text behavior with different browsers. I cannot say which browser of the 3 is acting peculiar. Before I give out the details of my problem let me illustrate the issue I am encountering..

**Outputs::**

[image][image][image]

**layout format::**

[image][image][image]

Now the corresponding css codes are as follows::

```
 #feature_links_inner_block {
            width: 205px;
            height: 390px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #side_nav_links {
            width: 99%;
            height: 375px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .one_third_side_nav_block {
            width: 100%;
            height: 125px;
        }
        .one_third_side_nav_block h4 {
            margin: 3px 0px 0px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "marcellus sc";
            font-size: 19px;
            color: #f1d000;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .one_third_side_nav_block img {
            float: left;
            margin: 1px 3px 0px 1px;
        }
        .one_third_side_nav_block p {
            margin: 3px 0px 5px 0px;
            font-family: "trebuchet ms",Arimo, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #fff;
        }
```

HTML::

```
<div id="feature_links_inner_block">

     <div id="side_nav_links">
        ....
        <a href="news_media_blurbs.html">
            <div class="one_third_side_nav_block white_bottom_border">
                 <h4>News, Media &amp; Blurbs</h4>
                 <img src="../Images/png/apply.png" alt="News and Media image" />
                 <p>What is happening now?</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

I am trying to figure out what is causing this to happen. Its the same code but rendered different. I have tried to look at the computed values in each browser but they all seem to be the same. If anyone wants it i have the computed values of chrome and firefox copied as a text file.

Ideally I want the final output to look like the chrome output. This is just a small part of the page. I have other sections in the page which runs into similar issue.

Is chrome rendering correctly and the rest 2 not? or is it the other way around?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Addendum::: I forgot to mention that I am using HTML5-Boilerplate as my template

Comment: If you want it to look like the Chrome output, just throw a line break `<br/>` into the H4, between the ampersand and the word "Blurbs":

`<h4>News, Media &amp;<br/> Blurbs</h4>`

Comment: That would add a break even on chrome output

Comment: And? It would have the exact same effect. It would just be uniform across all browsers instead of only displaying like that in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you. That does solve the problem. but out of curiosity why does chrome not process that extra "break" tag? or better yet why did chrome render the code with a "break" before the tag was even introduced to make the other browsers' output same?

Comment: It wasn't. Basically what was happening was that Chrome was detecting a width, different from the other browsers, for that containing div, which was not wide enough to accommodate the entire H4 on one single line and thus was wrapping the text. By adding in a line break break manually, you are basically just forcing the text wrap at the desired point, allowing it to look the same across all browsers. If you had wanted all of the H4 text on one line, I would have suggested reducing the font-size by a single point which, probably, would have allowed the H4 to fit on one line across all browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Please if you dont mind copy the answer that you provided me into the answer section so that i can check it as accepted answer and you will get the rep points that you deserve. thanks again.

Comment: No problem @Sai, glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the div containing the H4 element was not rendering with a large enough width in Chrome to display the H4 on a single line and the text was wrapping. The OP said that this was actually the desired effect, so I suggested manually adding in a line break to force the H4 to break at the desired point.

If the OP had wanted the H4 to remain on one line, they could have, alternatively, reduced the font-size by a point or two to allow the H4 enough room to exist on one line across all browsers.

This ended up working for the OP:

```
<h4>News, Media &amp;<br/>Blurbs</h4>
```